# why downcast fails at runtime

Tags: c#, casting

I want to know why below downcast fails @ run time:

case 1:

```
Object y = 10.23;
Console.WriteLine(y.GetType()); //System.Double
int z = (int)y;// fails @ runtime
Console.ReadKey();
```

case 2:

```
Double y = 10.23;
Console.WriteLine(y.GetType());//System.Double
int z = (int)y;//success
Console.ReadKey();
```

In both the cases the type of y is System.Double, still why downcst fails in first case?

Comment: Marc is of course correct. For a longer analysis of why this sort of cast is not legal, see my article on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first example; unboxing (what you show) is **different** to downcasting or conversion; it is perhaps unfortunate that C# uses the same syntax for all 3.

You **must** unbox value-types (such as int/double) correctly. Or use `Convert.ToInt32(y)` which has the logic for this embedded.

In the second example, this is a conversion (not an unbox, and not a downcast). Conversions are defined either in the language spec (like in this case) or via custom static operators.

The difference is `object`. The box changes **everything**.

Comment: thanks, I got the point.
In first case is there ant other way of unboxing rather than  Convert.ToInt32(y)

Comment: Yes - you can do `(int)(double)y`, which unboxes (correctly) to `double`, and *then* does a *conversion* to `int`.

Comment: yes, worked.so the chain is boxing-->unboxing and that -->conversion.
Thanks for ur help.

Comment: The rules can be summed up thus: 1) source reference type, target reference type - upcast/downcast/interface case; 2) source reference type, target value type - unboxing; 3) source value type, target reference type - boxing; 4) source value type, target value type - conversion. Of those 4, only the last one involves actual widening or narrowing conversions. Of course, this all assumes no overloaded conversion operators, as those can do anything they want.