# Why does this conversion doesn't work?

Tags: c#, casting

following code behaves strange (at least for me):

```
int testValue = 1234;

this.ConversionTest( testValue );

private void ConversionTest( object value )
{
    long val_1 = (long) (int) value; // works
    long val_2 = (long) value;       // InvalidCastException
}
```

I don't understand why the direct (explicit) cast to long doesn't work.
Can someone explain this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very commonly asked question. My article on the subject is here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Comment: Note also that this is a duplicate of many previous Stack Overflow questions, such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812172 or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651754 or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667169 or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085097

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `value` parameter of your `ConversionTest` method is typed as `object`; this means that any value types -- for example, `int` -- passed to the method will be boxed.

Boxed values can only be unboxed to exactly the same type:

- When you do `(long)(int)value` you're first unboxing `value` to an `int` (its original type) and then converting that `int` to a `long`.
- When you do `(long)value` you're attempting to unbox the boxed `int` to a `long`, which is illegal.